# Ubuntu server can't update/install. systemd Failed to start Wait for Network to be Configured

Tags: networking, systemd, 17.10, svn

I already selected Bridge Adapter to the network settings. `sudo apt-get update` is also not working. Actually not only. I think everything that requires `apt-get install` is not working. Searched google for more than 11 hrs now and still nothing. This is my final resort. Need help please!

[image: boot-up screenshot]

[image: svn installation]

@kostix from stackoverflow told me to `systemctl status systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` and `journalctl -u systemd-networkd-wait-online -e`and it gave me this

[image: screenshot of log in terminal]

Comment: My experience with the new 17.10 and network is that after changing it from Virtual settings is wait a bit and or try again it will catch on

Comment: If it's possible to restart your system do if not don't!

Comment: What do you mean "restart your system"? i already rebooted it a couple of times. Or do you mean my host OS?

Comment: ok I see didn't take note of that!

Comment: Have you disabled IPV6 perhaps?

Comment: @Rolf I think I haven't.